# Sitecore 10.2 creates session data "sc_ct_trk"

Tags: session-state, cookies

We recently migrated from Sitecore 9 to 10.2 and now we see a strange cookie in the session data named `sc_ct_trk`. I looked all up the internet and found no reference to what this is or how to disable it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Sitecore can collect [telemetry metrics](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0057838) associated with certain Sitecore environments to help understand how their platform is used.

One of the metrics is called `XM.Foundation.Core.Nexus.WebSessions` and it counts the number of web sessions on the website. To avoid tracking the same session multiple times, Sitecore saves a flag `sc_ct_trk=1` to the current session data after the session has been counted by the telemetry client. Therefore, in all subsequent requests Sitecore will know that this session has already been added to the metric and there is no need to count it again.

As far as I can see, this flag is saved to the session storage rather than cookies so this flag is only accessible from your server infrastructure and not visible to the end users. The only possible value is `1` and no personal data is associated with this metric.

This functionality is implemented in one of the core Sitecore HTTP modules hence I would not recommend disabling it without contacting Sitecore. This [knowledge base article](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0424335) says that Sitecore can provide a no-track license file and you can contact your Sitecore account representative for more information.